# How to put a scrollbar in an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, scrollbar, scrollview

I created a new `Activity`, but the page is not scrollable .. how can I do to scroll?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
  android:background="@color/gray_light2">>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
  android:src="@drawable/impostazioni" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"></ImageView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"           
  android:textColor="#424243" 
  android:id="@+id/personName" 
  android:text=" Notifica a comparsa" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/check1"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/personSurname"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:textColor="#424243" 
  android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
  android:text=" Connessione Amico" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/check2" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  android:textColor="#424243" 
  android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
  android:text="Notifica quando un amico si connette all'applicazione"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:textColor="#424243" 
  android:id="@+id/TextView03" 
  android:text=" Amico nelle vicinanze" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/check3" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  android:textColor="#424243" 
  android:id="@+id/TextView04" 
  android:text="Notifica quando un amico si trova nelle vicinanze"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/TextView03" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:textColor="#424243" 
  android:id="@+id/TextView05" 
  android:text=" Suoneria" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/TextView04" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
  android:layout_marginTop="18dp"></TextView>
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TextView05" 
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></CheckBox>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:textColor="#424243" 
  android:id="@+id/TextView07" 
  android:text=" Vibrazione" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CheckBox02" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  android:textColor="#424243" 
  android:id="@+id/TextView08" 
  android:text="Attiva la vibrazione per le notifiche"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/TextView07" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  android:textColor="#424243" 
  android:id="@+id/TextView06" 
  android:text="Attiva la suoneria come suono di notifica"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/TextView05" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/CheckBox02" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/TextView06" 
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
  android:layout_marginTop="14dp"></CheckBox>
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/check1" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" 
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></CheckBox>
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/check2" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/personSurname" 
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
  android:layout_marginTop="14dp"></CheckBox>
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/check3" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02" 
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
  android:layout_marginTop="21dp"></CheckBox>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  android:textColor="#424243" 
  android:id="@+id/personSurname" 
  android:text="Mostra una notifica quando l'applicazione è in background"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/personName" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You accidentally the whole Activity.

Comment: what? I did not understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to have all widget inside  this linear layout, as ScrollView will not support only one widget to be scroll, so take all inside that linear layout . It works fine for me

Answer (score 3):

Set the `layout_height` of the `RelativeLayout` to `wrap_content`, then enclose it in a `ScrollView` with `layout_height` and `layout_width` set to `fill_parent`.

Comment: [2011-11-29 02:26:24 - a_l7] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="Status" android:background="#CCCCCC"> android:layout_weight="2.38"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/showdata1" android:textSize="12sp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="56dp" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

        <TextView android:text="Name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/textView2"
             android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="38dp" android:background="#CCCCCC">></TextView>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/showdata2" android:layout_height="38dp" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Address"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="#CCCCCC" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/showdata3" android:textSize="12sp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="32dp" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

        <TextView android:text="Email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:background="#CCCCCC" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/showdata4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Phone1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="#CCCCCC" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_weight="2.28"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/showdata5" android:textSize="12sp"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="32dp" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>


        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Phone2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:background="#CCCCCC" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/showdata6" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: here you can see, i put all views inside linear layout,Scroll view will not allow you to take two view inside it to scroll, unless u take another layout inside it. Hope this will solve ur problem